# Add callback to existing webrtc js function

Tags: javascript, callback, webrtc

I have webrtc in a web app set up using mostly demo code. It's working using a setTimeout to stop the recording. I'd like to add a click event to a button as an alternative way to stop the recording.
From the demo code, I've broken off the bit i want as a new function saveAudioFile(). It is triggered by the playSequence function passing the recorder object that is instantiated in the playSequence function. 
What I want to know is how to trigger the saveAudioFile function alternatively through a mouse click (and stop the timeout). I've created a button and click event listener, but the issue I have is with passing the 'recorder' object (which is created in another function and out of scope) without which the function won't work.
This is all about callbacks (I think) and I still haven't wrapped my head around them. What do I need to do to be able to use the 'recorder' object in the playSequence function to stop the recording alternatively through a mouseclick (while maintaining the timeout fallback)?

nb. The firing of the playSequence function through a setTimeout is intentional- I need it to start 3 seconds after the page loads. Just mentioning in case it was a cause of confusion/questions.

```
function saveAudioFile(recorder)
            {
                // stop recording
                recorder.stopRecording(function() {

                    //ajax function to upload audio and save as file- working

                });
            }


        function playSequence()
        {           
                    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: false, audio: true }).then(function(camera) {
                    // recording configuration/hints/parameters
                    var recordingHints = {
                        type: 'audio'
                    };

                    // initiating the recorder
                    var recorder = RecordRTC(camera, recordingHints);

                    // starting recording here
                    recorder.startRecording();

                    // auto stop recording after 30 seconds
                    var milliSeconds = 10 * 1000;
                    setTimeout(saveAudioFile(recorder) , milliSeconds);
                });
            });
        }

        setTimeout(
                function(){ 
                playSequence();
                }, 
                3000
                );

        jQuery('#endrecording').click(function() {
            saveAudioFile();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why You wouldn't put the event listener inside `playSequence` function? You won't be able to pass `recorder` object to `click` listener as it does not exist yet - it'll be created after `3s` right? :)

Plus, this part: `setTimeout(saveAudioFile(recorder) , milliSeconds);`
seems like it won't work, does it?
When using functions with arguments as callbacks, you either have know with what arguments the callback will be called - f.e. event listener callbacks are called with specific `Event` object - or you should pass an anonymous function, that calls your functions with your custom arguments.

Haven't tested, that's first that comes to my mind:

```js
function playSequence() {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: false,
    audio: true
  }).then(function(camera) {
    // recording configuration/hints/parameters
    var recordingHints = {
      type: 'audio'
    };

    // initiating the recorder
    var recorder = RecordRTC(camera, recordingHints);

    // starting recording here
    recorder.startRecording();

    // auto stop recording after 30 secods
    var milliSeconds = 30 * 1000;
    document
      .getElementById('endrecording')
      .addEventListener('click', function(){ saveAudioFile(recorder) };

    setTimeout(
      function(){ saveAudioFile(recorder) }, 
      milliSeconds
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Did the job.